# Como deixar centralizado um icone juntamente com um LI adicionado via CSS dentro de uma UL

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como centralizar um ícone implementado via `background url()` no `css` junto com meu `li`, o problema é que quando eu adiciono o ícone, ele afasta pro lado direito o meu `li` e como ele aparece colado no `li` tenho que da um `margin`, e quando faço isso ai é que ele afasta mais ainda e fica tudo descentralizado em relação ao meu `header` como eu mostro nos prints com e sem essas alterações. Tem alguma maneira pra que isso não aconteça?

```css
CSS--


.main_footer_content{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 1em;
background-color: #010f19;
max-width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.main_footer_content article{
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column;
flex: 1;
text-align: center;
padding: 1em 0;
}

.main_footer_content article header{
padding: 1em 0;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.2em; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.main_footer_menus{
padding: 0.5em 0; 
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

}


.main_footer_menus li{
padding: 0.5em 0;
flex: 1;
}

.main_footer_menus li a{
color: #FFF;

}

.main_footer_menus li::before{
content: url(../img/verified.png); 
margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
HTML--

<section class="main_footer_content">

        <h1 class="font_zero">Vem ver nossas novidades!</h1>


        <article>
            <header>
                <h1 class="menu_site_titulo">Menu do site</h1>
            </header>
            <ul class="main_footer_menus">

                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Podutos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>

            </ul>

        </article>
        
        </section>
```

[image: ANTES]

[image: DEPOIS]

Comment: cole o código, e deixe as imagens para mostrar somente o resultado. Era melhor um exemplo minimo!

Comment: Sem o código não da para te dar uma resposta precisa, por favor edite a sua pergunta e inclua seu HTML e CSS

Comment: ai está... desculpa...

Comment: Tony era pra vc editar colocando o CSS da LI inteiro, conforme estava nas imagems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie o `::before` no `a` e não no `li`, e use `position: absolute` para posicionar o ícone com `left` negativo, lembrando que o `a` deve ter `position: relative`. Como os ícones terão posição absoluta, não irão interferir no alinhamento dos links.

Exemplo:

```css
.main_footer_menus li a::before{
content: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fugue/icon_shadowless/tick-circle-frame.png);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -20px;
display: flex;
}

a{
   position: relative;
}

/* exemplos. não use os códigos abaixo */
article{
   text-align: center;
}

ul, li{
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.main_footer_menus li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
}

body{
   background: black;
   font-size: 22px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<article>
   <header>
       <h1 class="menu_site_titulo">Menu do site</h1>
   </header>
   <ul class="main_footer_menus">

       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Podutos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>

   </ul>

</article>
```

Comment: Sam, deu pra resolver sim com essa solução sim... Obg por disponibilizar um pouco do seu tempo pra me dar essa força! Grande abraço!!!

Comment: Que bom. Se resolveu marque a resposta com ✔. ObG!

Comment: Tony, vi que marcou a minha resposta e desmarcou em seguida. Era isso mesmo?

Comment: É que só pode marcar uma resposta. Se marcar outra desmarca a anterior, mas vc pode recompensar respostas também votando positivo na seta pra cima.

Comment: pois é... Percebi isso agora...hehe
Tanto a sua resposta como a do amigo de cima solucionaram meu problema de formas diferentes... O certo é da um joinha pros dois neh...rs

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode basicamente colocar `position: absolute` e `transform: translateX(-21px)` no pseudo-elemento ::before que vc resolve a situação. O `position:absolute` vai fazer o elemento "sair do fluxo" assim ele fica "flutuando" dentro do `LI` que precisei colocar `position:relative`, e com o `transform: translateX(-21px)` vc coloca o `::before` `16px` que é a largura dele `+5px` que seria a margem entre ele e o texto.

```css
article {
  text-align: center;
}
.main_footer_content{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 1em;
background-color: #010f19;
max-width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.main_footer_content article{
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column;
flex: 1;
text-align: center;
padding: 1em 0;
}

.main_footer_content article header{
padding: 1em 0;
color: #000;
font-size: 1.2em; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.main_footer_menus{
padding: 0.5em 0; 
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

}


.main_footer_menus li{
padding: 0.5em 0;
flex: 1;
position: relative;
}

.main_footer_menus li a{
color: #000;

}

.main_footer_menus li::before{
content: url(https://unsplash.it/16/16); 
position: absolute;
transform: translateX(-21px);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <h1 class="menu_site_titulo">Menu do site</h1>
  </header>
  <ul class="main_footer_menus">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Podutos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>

  </ul>
  
</article>
```

Comment: Hugo, Sua solução me ajudou a entender como resolver alguns outros problemas e esse também... Muito obrigado por me ensinar a melhorar a visualização do meu post e a resolver o meu problema... Obg por dedicar um pouco do seu tempo também... Obg pela força e um grande abraço!

Comment: @TonyIvan sem problemas, a vida é um aprendizado constante. Estamos aqui para ajudar. Se alguma resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado da resposta escolhida, assim o site não fica com sua pergunta em aberto mesmo ela já tendo sido resolvida.  Abs